# Load a dynamic layout at runtime

Tags: android, layout

I have an Android application that loads a quiz using a webservice. That quiz is made of several questions so I need to build the layout dynamically because the number of questions may vary.

My interface is something like this:

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical">
<ViewFlipper>

Question and possible answers ...

</ViewFlipper>
<HorizontalScrollView>
one button dynamically created for each question so I can navigate through the quiz...
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

I have created another xml containing a sample of the layout that should be used to show the question and answers that should be instatiated for each question and injected inside the ViewFlipper.

My question is what should be the right approach to do this task? Do I need to manually create and insert all Views inside the viewflipper or can I use the template I've created?

Each question will also have some buttons (to select the answer) and I need to save the results to I can submit them to the server and calculate the final score.

I would appreciate some ideas to accomplish this even if I have to change the structure of the application to make it easier to code.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you thought about an AdapterView like ListView or a ViewPager?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating and inserting your widgets in code at run time.  Otherwise you will have a fixed number of items available to you from the XML layout you use (unless you then start dynamically creating and adding widgets to that layout, which is what you can just do right off the bat)

All you need to do is get a handle to the view you want to add items to, create the desired widget and then call the addView method of the target view.  Here is an example of dynamically adding multiple TextViews from some test code I wrote:

```
//Getting String[] data from intent
      String parts[] = myIntent.getStringExtra("parts");

      int length = parts.length;

      //Control ID's must NOT be zero, starting at 10
      int ids = 10; 
      for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) 
      {       
          RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); 
          TextView nextItem = new TextView(this);

      //Again, NEVER ZERO 
       nextItem.setId(ids); 
       nextItem.setText(parts[i]);
      //Checking if this is the first item added and setting it to be below the info widget (you can use any widget with an ID in your view)
       if(i==0) 
        { 
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.info); 
        } 
       else
        {
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, ids-1); 
        }
        nextItem.setLayoutParams(params);
        thisView.addView(nextItem, params);
        ids++; 
       }
      }
```